# Odd bug converting char to int (Objective C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, char, int

I have an app set up where I convert an NSString into an array of char variables, and I'm trying to convert some of the chars to integers (basically to parse the numbers out of the string). But when I try to convert them to int variables, they suddenly change value.

For example:

```
char thechar = array[7]; //to make sure the issue isn't related to the array

NSLog(@"%c %i %i",thechar,(int) thechar, [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:thechar] intValue]);
```

returns this:

```
3 51 51
```

Both methods (that I've found) of converting it seem to change the value to 51. Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: @dlev: I would put your comment as an answer, since it is the answer.

Comment: @dlev So how would I go about getting the '3' as an integer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out: just convert it to NSString and then get the intValue.

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", thechar] intValue];
```

Comment: you can (and should) accept your own answer, so people know it's solved

Answer (score 3):

51 is the numeric value for the literal character '3'. It dates back to the ASCII standard, though many common Unicode encodings maintain the value as well.

You can pretty reliably just subtract 48 (or '0') to get the number:

```
int num = (int)(numAsChar - '0');
```

Alternatively, if you want to convert an entire string, you can use [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/):

```
int num = atoi(myNumberString);
```

Comment: That first one hurts my brain - it looks like you're subtracting a string.

Comment: @MusiGenesis C++ in general hurts my brain. I'm happy I do most of my work in C# these days.

Comment: I wish I could do C# again - I'm in the objective-C world now.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. The subtracting 48 wasn't what I wanted, because it could be any number, but what DID work was converting it to an NSString with stringWithFormat, and then doing intValue to the string.

Comment: @Greg Glad you got it solved. You may want to post your findings as an  answer, since that's what actually fixed the issue.